# Normalize a deeply nested json in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to normalize a json file that looks like this (a small snippet):

```
[{'trimestre': 'A2000',
  'cours': [{"sigle":"TECH 20701", "titre":"La cybersécurité et le gestionnaire",'etudiants': [{'matricule': '22000803',
      'nom': 'Boyer,AndrÃ©',
      'note': 'C+',
      'valeur': 2.3},
     {'matricule': '22000829',
      'nom': 'Keighan,Maylis',
      'note': 'A+',
      'valeur': 4.3},
     {'matricule': '22000869',
      'nom': 'Lahaie,Lyes',
      'note': 'B+',
      'valeur': 3.3},
     {'matricule': '22000973',
      'nom': 'Conerardy,Rawaa',
      'note': 'B+',
      'valeur': 3.3},
      ]}]
```

Im trying to get a table that will look like this:

```
                                    **"trimestre"** (columns)
      **"sigle" + "titre"** (index): *valeur*
```

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = pd.read_json('DataTP2.json')
print(data)
```

I tried using the normalize function like this

```
result = json_normalize(data, 'cours',['trimestre'])
print(result)
```

But I am getting an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Basically I want "sigle" + "titre" (from "cours") as an index, "trimestre" as a column and the mean value of "valeur" as values in the table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not post output as image. Copy past it in the question. Its really hard to get data from image.

Comment: @poojan Sorry first time using stack overflow I changed it.

Comment: The problem is you have 1 index for several 'valeur', witch one do you want ?

Comment: @FlorianBernard "sigle" alone would be best

Answer (score 0):

Here you are :

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

test = [{'trimestre': 'A2000',
  'cours': [{"sigle":"TECH 20701", "titre":"La cybersécurité et le gestionnaire",'etudiants': [{'matricule': '22000803',
      'nom': 'Boyer,AndrÃ©',
      'note': 'C+',
      'valeur': 2.3},
     {'matricule': '22000829',
      'nom': 'Keighan,Maylis',
      'note': 'A+',
      'valeur': 4.3},
     {'matricule': '22000869',
      'nom': 'Lahaie,Lyes',
      'note': 'B+',
      'valeur': 3.3},
     {'matricule': '22000973',
      'nom': 'Conerardy,Rawaa',
      'note': 'B+',
      'valeur': 3.3},
      ]}]}]


results = defaultdict(list)

for trimestre in data:
    results["trimestre"].append(trimestre["trimestre"])
    for cours in trimestre["cours"]:
        results["index"].append(f"{cours['sigle']} {cours['titre']}")
        results["valeur"].append(cours["sigle"])

df = pd.DataFrame(results["valeur"], columns=results["trimestre"], index=results["index"])
```

Results

```py
>>> print(df)
                                                   A2000
TECH 20701 La cybersécurité et le gestionnaire  TECH 20701
```

Comment: I am still getting a TypeError: string indices must be integers error when trying your code

Comment: @Jacky I have updated my code, use json module instead on the pandas one.