# Normalizing deeply nested JSON in Python incorrectly yielding hundreds of columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to normalize the following JSON:

```
{
    "href": "url1",
    "items": [
        {
            "count": 6,
            "items": [
                {
                    "href": "url2",
                    "count": 2,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "href": "url3",
                            "description": {
                                "year": 2017,
                                "make": "ACURA",
                                "model": "ILX",
                                "trim": "4D SEDAN ACURAWATCH PLUS",
                                "subSeries": "ACURAWATCH"
                            },
                            "adjustedPricing": {
                                "wholesale": {
                                    "above": 18050,
                                    "average": 15650,
                                    "below": 13250
                                },
                                "adjustedBy": {
                                    "Odometer": "30352"
                                }
                            },
                            "wholesale": {
                                "above": 17600,
                                "average": 15200,
                                "below": 12800
                            },
                            "averageOdometer": 36939,
                            "odometerUnits": "miles",
                            "averageGrade": 43,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sampleSize": "6"
                        },
                        {
                            "href": "url4",
                            "description": {
                                "year": 2017,
                                "make": "ACURA",
                                "model": "ILX",
                                "trim": "4D SEDAN",
                                "subSeries": "NONE"
                            },
                            "adjustedPricing": {
                                "wholesale": {
                                    "above": 17950,
                                    "average": 16600,
                                    "below": 15250
                                },
                                "adjustedBy": {
                                    "Odometer": "30352"
                                }
                            },
                            "wholesale": {
                                "above": 17900,
                                "average": 16550,
                                "below": 15200
                            },
                            "averageOdometer": 31235,
                            "odometerUnits": "miles",
                            "averageGrade": 37,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sampleSize": "47"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "href": "url5",
                    "count": 2,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "href": "url6",
                            "description": {
                                "year": 2017,
                                "make": "ACURA",
                                "model": "ILX",
                                "trim": "4D SEDAN PREMIUM",
                                "subSeries": "PREMIUM"
                            },
                            "adjustedPricing": {
                                "wholesale": {
                                    "above": 16200,
                                    "average": 14700,
                                    "below": 13200
                                },
                                "adjustedBy": {
                                    "Odometer": "53824"
                                }
                            },
                            "wholesale": {
                                "above": 18500,
                                "average": 16950,
                                "below": 15450
                            },
                            "averageOdometer": 30090,
                            "odometerUnits": "miles",
                            "averageGrade": 36,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sampleSize": "15"
                        },
                        {
                            "href": "url7",
                            "description": {
                                "year": 2017,
                                "make": "ACURA",
                                "model": "ILX",
                                "trim": "4D SEDAN TECH PKG",
                                "subSeries": "TECH PKG"
                            },
                            "adjustedPricing": {
                                "wholesale": {
                                    "above": 17850,
                                    "average": 15950,
                                    "below": 14050
                                },
                                "adjustedBy": {
                                    "Odometer": "53824"
                                }
                            },
                            "wholesale": {
                                "above": 19800,
                                "average": 17850,
                                "below": 15950
                            },
                            "averageOdometer": 27247,
                            "odometerUnits": "miles",
                            "averageGrade": 37,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sampleSize": "21"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "href": "url8",
                    "count": 1,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "href": "url9",
                            "description": {
                                "year": 2017,
                                "make": "ACURA",
                                "model": "MDX AWD",
                                "trim": "4D SUV 3.5L",
                                "subSeries": "NONE"
                            },
                            "adjustedPricing": {
                                "wholesale": {
                                    "above": 28900,
                                    "average": 27400,
                                    "below": 25900
                                },
                                "adjustedBy": {
                                    "Odometer": "23753"
                                }
                            },
                            "wholesale": {
                                "above": 28000,
                                "average": 26500,
                                "below": 25000
                            },
                            "averageOdometer": 34427,
                            "odometerUnits": "miles",
                            "averageGrade": 36,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sampleSize": "79",
                            "bestMatch": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "href": "url10",
                    "count": 1,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "href": "url11",
                            "description": {
                                "year": 2017,
                                "make": "ACURA",
                                "model": "MDX AWD",
                                "trim": "4D SUV 3.5L",
                                "subSeries": "NONE"
                            },
                            "adjustedPricing": {
                                "wholesale": {
                                    "above": 27200,
                                    "average": 25700,
                                    "below": 24200
                                },
                                "adjustedBy": {
                                    "Odometer": "43735"
                                }
                            },
                            "wholesale": {
                                "above": 28000,
                                "average": 26500,
                                "below": 25000
                            },
                            "averageOdometer": 34427,
                            "odometerUnits": "miles",
                            "averageGrade": 36,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sampleSize": "79",
                            "bestMatch": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "href": "url12",
                    "count": 1,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "href": "url13",
                            "description": {
                                "year": 2017,
                                "make": "ACURA",
                                "model": "MDX AWD",
                                "trim": "4D SUV 3.5L",
                                "subSeries": "NONE"
                            },
                            "adjustedPricing": {
                                "wholesale": {
                                    "above": 27700,
                                    "average": 26200,
                                    "below": 24700
                                },
                                "adjustedBy": {
                                    "Odometer": "38097"
                                }
                            },
                            "wholesale": {
                                "above": 28000,
                                "average": 26500,
                                "below": 25000
                            },
                            "averageOdometer": 34427,
                            "odometerUnits": "miles",
                            "averageGrade": 36,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sampleSize": "79",
                            "bestMatch": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "href": "url14",
                    "count": 1,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "href": "url15",
                            "description": {
                                "year": 2017,
                                "make": "ACURA",
                                "model": "MDX AWD",
                                "trim": "4D SUV 3.5L",
                                "subSeries": "NONE"
                            },
                            "adjustedPricing": {
                                "wholesale": {
                                    "above": 28100,
                                    "average": 26500,
                                    "below": 25000
                                },
                                "adjustedBy": {
                                    "Odometer": "33627"
                                }
                            },
                            "wholesale": {
                                "above": 28000,
                                "average": 26500,
                                "below": 25000
                            },
                            "averageOdometer": 34427,
                            "odometerUnits": "miles",
                            "averageGrade": 36,
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "sampleSize": "79",
                            "bestMatch": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "errors": [
        {
            "count": 0,
            "errors": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried using Pandas' json_normalize function which returns 1 row with 3 columns (href, items, errors). I also tried plugging this into every solution from [Normalize a deeply nested json in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772980/normalize-a-deeply-nested-json-in-pandas) but it ends up returning a dataframe with hundreds of columns. Does anyone know how to correctly flatten this JSON so that it can be entered into SQL?

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

For recursive structure like this,  you can use recursion to flatten it.

1. `js` is the sample JSON you provided (had to change `true` to `True`)
2. if key *items* is present,  `pop()` it so it's not appended to `list` being built. Do recursive call to all elements in list.  Append it to list without the the *items* key
3. if key *items* is not present - have recursed all the way,  so just add to `list`
4. for transparency I've included in output the recursive depth and indicator if flattened item has children or not

```
def flat(js, l, level=0):
    i = {}
    if "items" in js.keys():
        i = js.pop("items")
        for js2 in i:
            flat(js2, l, level+1)
        l.append({**{"level":level, "haschild":True}, **js})
    else:
        l.append({**{"level":level, "haschild":False}, **js})
    return l

l = []
l =flat(js, l)
df = pd.json_normalize(l)
print(df.iloc[:,:10].to_string(index=False))
```

**sample output**

```
 level  haschild   href  averageOdometer odometerUnits  averageGrade currency sampleSize  description.year description.make
     3     False   url3          36939.0         miles          43.0      USD          6            2017.0            ACURA
     3     False   url4          31235.0         miles          37.0      USD         47            2017.0            ACURA
     2      True   url2              NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN               NaN              NaN
     3     False   url6          30090.0         miles          36.0      USD         15            2017.0            ACURA
     3     False   url7          27247.0         miles          37.0      USD         21            2017.0            ACURA
     2      True   url5              NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN               NaN              NaN
     3     False   url9          34427.0         miles          36.0      USD         79            2017.0            ACURA
     2      True   url8              NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN               NaN              NaN
     3     False  url11          34427.0         miles          36.0      USD         79            2017.0            ACURA
     2      True  url10              NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN               NaN              NaN
     3     False  url13          34427.0         miles          36.0      USD         79            2017.0            ACURA
     2      True  url12              NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN               NaN              NaN
     3     False  url15          34427.0         miles          36.0      USD         79            2017.0            ACURA
     2      True  url14              NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN               NaN              NaN
     1      True    NaN              NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN               NaN              NaN
     0      True   url1              NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN        NaN               NaN              NaN
```